# How to build an iOS binary without setting an Apple Developer account and team?

Tags: ios, certificate, provisioning-profile, ipa, account

I'm using `Xcode` 6.3.2, and I'd like to let another people to build and create the `.ipa` files of my projects, but I don't want neither to expose my `Apple Developer` account information, nor create users for them in my team... is that possible? Either by using `Xcode`, either by commands line.

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:** The goal is to prevent those external people from being able to submit apps to the `App Store` by means of my `Apple Developer` account and from being able to see the other apps managed in the account.

**EDIT2:** Does providing the distribution certificate to external people make possible to them to submit binaries to the `App Store`?

Answer (score 3):

After reading your edits, I think I understand more clearly what you are trying to do.  Basically, you will simply need to provide the other members of your team with the following:

- The private key used to generate your app store distribution
  certificate.
- The distribution certificate
- The app store distribution
  provisioning profile

This will allow those team members to work on, and build the app for the app store.  Without your Apple developer ID password, they will not be able to log into iTunes Connect to see the other apps you have.  While they will be able to build the app for app store distribution, you (as the only one with the apple ID password) will have to be the one to submit the compiled app to the store.

So basically, your development team will create the apps.  When you're ready for release, they can do an "Archive" in Xcode to create the .app that has been signed for the app store (using the provisioning profile and signing identity that you provided them in the three files I mention above. They will zip up the .app and the .dSym files into a .zip and send it to you. You will then log into iTunes Connect and set upt the app to be ready for the new binary, and then use the Application loader to upload the .zip to apple for review.  Once you have gotten a successful review, **you** will again log into iTunes Connect to release the app.  So at no point will the developers have access to submit apps or see other apps you have in the store.

Also, the development team will not need the provisioning profile, cert, and key until they need to build for the app store.  During the development phase, there is no problem with them using their own developer accounts to build and test the app.

One additional thing to note is that Apple is changing the roles that are available in iTunes connect.  You may want to review those new roles to see if some combination of those roles my work for your team setup.

From http://9to5mac.com/2015/06/12/wwdc-itunes-connect-testflight-limits-account-switching/

> After several apps are added to an account by its admin, developers
>   can now assign user roles to individuals on their team— app manager,
>   developer, or marketer— with each allowing varying access to iTunes
>   Connect features. App managers, for example, will be able to create
>   users, assign user roles, change pricing, and submit apps for review.
>   Marketers will get access to updating store metadata, uploading promo
>   material, and requesting promo codes. Users assigned the developer
>   role will be able to upload binaries, and view crash logs and store
>   metadata.

Comment: Nice answer @wottle. A bit unrelated, but do you know of any articles/posts that describe this and alternative forms of keeping signing/upload seperated?

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't found a great resource for this.  I've just had to learn by trial and error as Apple has changed how things behave slightly over the years.  Here's a good, but long article that walks you through all the steps for getting a cert, creating an app ID and provisioning profile, and how to manage it all.  I actually like his idea of having the important stuff (certs / keys) in a separate keychain, although we don't use it. https://roathe.wordpress.com/2011/04/05/how-to-manage-ios-provisioning-profiles/

Comment: Also, this is a good blog post on the subject: http://blog.jaredsinclair.com/post/116436789850/follow-these-guidelines-and-never-struggle-with

Answer (score 2):

Apple recently introduced Free-provisional-profile and/or free-developer-certificate support.
But it's limited (see below note).

To utilise that follow below steps suggested by Apple,

- In Xcode, add your Apple ID to Accounts preferences, described in Adding Your Apple ID Account in Xcode.

[image]

- In the project navigator, select the project and your target to
  display the project editor.
- Click General and choose your name fromthe Team pop-up menu.

[image]

- Connect the device to your Mac and choose your device from the Scheme toolbar menu.
- Below the Team pop-up menu, click Fix Issue.

  Xcode creates a free provisioning profile for you and the warning text         under the Team pop-up menu disappears.

[image]

- Click the Run button.

> **Note** that said support is limited, for example, the capability to sell things with "Apple Pay" would **not** even build with a free-certificate.

Comment: Its your general Apple ID not premium developer account it.. Hope its clear to you..

Comment: I tried and it requests an Apple ID enrolled to a developer program

Comment: Its because you are using Xcode 6.3.2. You need to use Xcode 7.0 beta for this feature. Sorry..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are several ways to solve your problem.

1. You can create .ipa file with you provisioning profile and give them the file, they can you use application called "Application Loader", they can use this application to upload the .ipa, this should resign your application with their provisioning profile. I did not try this but it should work.
2. When you create an archive of you application, it will be listed in "Organizer", go to that location, and give them that .app file alone. Then they can use any third party application(can be downloaded from Mac Appstore) to resign the application with their profile. In this case, you are completely hiding your information. They can even change the application icon, default image.. etc during the resigning process.
3. When you build your application in release mode an .app file is created, this is unsigned binary. You can search for .app file in your Xcode project itself. Just find the location, and give them that .app file alone. Then they can use any third party application(can be downloaded from Mac Appstore) to resign the application with their profile. In this case, you are completely hiding your information. They can even change the application icon, default image.. etc during the resigning process.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not able to test this without having my distribution certificate in my keychain: `xcodebuild -exportArchive -exportFormat ipa -archivePath
    <ARCHIVE_PATH> -exportPath
    <EXPORT_PATH> -exportProvisioningProfile
    <PROV_PROFILE>`. Would this need having the distribution certificate to work?

Comment: If you follow 3rd option, the .app will not have your information in that.. Choose simulator, remove all provisioning profiles for release build, and build the application in RELEASE mode, you will find .app in your Xcode. you can just handover that, it will not contain any of your details.

Answer (score 0):

No, There is no way to compile a .ipa without a provisioning profile (device compile, not simulator compile). To do this, you would go XCode->{AppTarget}->Build Settings->Code Signing->Code Signing Identity, and set 'Don't code sign".

Trying to compile afterwards will fail with

> CodeSign error: Code signing is required for product type
>   'Application' in SDK...[image]

---

> EDIT: The goal is to prevent those external people from being able to
>   submit apps to the App Store by means of my Apple Developer account
>   and from being able to see the other apps managed in the account.

You have two options:

1. Send them your Source code + XCode Project, and not the library.
2. Compile the code using "iOS Developer" Code Signing identity, and not "iOS Distribution" identity.

   - Anything signed with **iOS Developer** can never be sent to the AppStore.
   - Anything signed with **iOS Distribution** can never be run on a device
     unless it is downloaded from the AppStore.
   - They can never see what you have for sale, nor publish anything unless they have your AppleID username and password

Comment: iOS Distribution is needed to export a binary for ad hoc deployment, right? That is what they want, to be able to generate ad hoc ipa files